# how to calculate and store "groupings" in sql

Tags: sql

This is a SQL conceptual question.

Start with "Table 1" with a large number of records and a primary key.

Add a cross reference table called "Table 2" which holds key pairs from Table 1.  Each key pair means that two records should be in the same group.

How do you quickly calculate those groups assuming a large number of records?

Example:

### Table1

```
ID    other data
--    ----------
A     ...
B     ...
C     ...
D     ...
E     ...
F     ...
```

### Table 2

```
ID1    ID2
A      B      aka: A is equivalent to B. not a parent/child relationship
B      C
D      E
```

### Final Result

```
ID    Group
--    -----
A     1        A, B, & C are in a group
B     1
C     1
D     2        D & E are in a group
E     2
F     3        F is in a group by itself
```

Keep in mind that there are a large number of records.  Fast processing is desirable.  I'm not looking for someone to create something from scratch, but tell me if there is already a established technique for doing this sort of thing.  I've already written something myself, but it seems overly complex.

Note: edited for clarification with regard to answer by Paul.  Table 2 is not a parent / child relationship.  Its a relationship of equivalence.

Comment: From a theoretical standpoint it seems suboptimal to try and do this using only SQL algebra.  In the worst case you would have to perform `n` JOIN operations (where `n` is the length of Table 1), and a JOIN operation already takes `O(n^2)` time.  So this would be an `O(n^3)` task.  If `n` is large, it would take a very long time.  Instead you might consider representing the data as a graph (in your programming language of choice) and then running a simple `connected component` algorithm on the result.  That's only `O(n^2)` to set up the graph + `O(n)` to search it.

Comment: I think you should be able to use "START WITH... CONNECT BY".

Comment: @dg99 this is the sort of analysis I was looking for.  It makes me think about the problem in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in table 2 can be considered as 'parent-child' relationships (with id1 as the 'parent' and id2 as the 'child') then the result that you want can be achieved using the T-SQL below.  The key assumption being made here is that ids that don't appear in the 'child' column (id2) in table2 can be used as the root elements in a group.

```
with groups(parent, child) as 
(
    select t1.id as parent, t1.id as child
    from dbo.Table1 as t1
    where not exists
        (
            select 1
            from dbo.Table2 as t2
            where t2.id2 = t1.id
        )

    union all

    select g.parent, t2.id2
    from dbo.table2 as t2
    inner join groups as g
        on g.child = t2.id1
)

select g.child as id, DENSE_RANK() over (order by g.parent) as grp
from groups as g
order by g.child
```

Comment: It is not a parent/child relationship.  Its de-duplication logic such that Table 2 could be treated as A is equivalent to B, B is equivalent to C, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be of any use to you, but you seem to have modeled yourself into a tricky situation. Which means, of course, that you can model your way out of it. Here are a couple of suggestions.

Since if A=B and B=C then A=C, you could enter the data in Table2 as follows. This has the advantage of leaving the structure of Table2 as it is, but it still leads to a moderately tricky query. And it severely complicates some actions such as moving A to a different group.

```
ID1    ID2
A      A
A      B
A      C
D      D
D      E
F      F
```

Or, if you don't mind making a slight change to Table2, the data could look like this.

```
GROUP  ID
1      A
1      B
1      C
2      D
2      E
3      F
```

The advantage of this design, in case you haven't noticed already, is that it is amazingly similar to the output you wanted in the first place -- making for a correspondingly simple query. But if you work it out, you will see that the code to maintain this table will also be simple. You can easily insert a new ID as either a member of group 3 or as member of the group containing F. You can move any ID from one group to another, merge groups, split groups or even enter an ID into multiple groups (if that is allowed).

Good modeling can eliminate a lot of atrocious code.